# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in ...... "?:"

Tags: php, syntax, wrapper

I have a problem in a line of my code. On localhost it works smoothly. On host, it displays this error:

> **Parse error:** syntax error, unexpected ':' in (..../library.php) on line 94

**This is line 94:**

```
$Pay['environment'] = getenv('PAY_ENV') ?: self::PAY_ENV;
```

PHP Version 5.2.17. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can try this `$Pay['environment'] = getenv('PAY_ENV') ? '' : self::PAY_ENV;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The abreviated `?:` syntax was not added until PHP 5.3.  You will need to use the full ternary expression.  Something like this should work.

```
$Pay['environment'] = getenv('PAY_ENV') ? getenv('PAY_ENV') : self::PAY_ENV;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: Thank you Jason, so it worked!